# Mapbox Drop-in UI with React-Native and Android Native UI View causing app crash

Tags: react-native, mapbox-android

Some details and context:

I've been trying to get turn-by-turn navigation running in our react-native app using the Mapbox drop-in UI and/or SDKs. We've created a native-ui bridge to react-native and can call basic commands however on attempting to render the actual mapbox UI, we get an app crash. Logs to follow - do not worry. The Mapbox SDK seems to start up from the android logs, but then we get a fatal signal. We also have some hermes and SoLoader errors above in the logs that aren't present when not bringing in the Mapbox code. Does anyone have any pointers or advice on what I may be doing wrong?

We've stripped out into a brand new react project just to see if we can get it running - so I have plenty of code examples and logs to share.

Mapbox Drop-In UI xml (mapbox_activity_navigation_view.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:accessToken="@string/mapbox_access_token"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
/>
```

Our Android MapboxNavigationView.kt:

```
package com.mapboxpoc

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
import com.mapbox.navigation.dropin.NavigationView

class MapboxNavigationView(private val callerContext: ReactApplicationContext) : SimpleViewManager<NavigationView>() {
    companion object {
        const val REACT_CLASS = "MapboxNavigationView"
    }

    override fun getName() = REACT_CLASS

    override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext): NavigationView {
        val mapboxNavigationView = LayoutInflater.from(reactContext).inflate(
            R.layout.mapbox_activity_navigation_view,
            null
        )

        mapboxNavigationView.api.routeReplayEnabled(true);
        return mapboxNavigationView
    }
}
```

Android MapboxNavigationPackage.kt:

```
package com.mapboxpoc

import android.view.View
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager

class MapboxNavigationPackage: ReactPackage {
    override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): MutableList<ViewManager<out View, out ReactShadowNode<*>>> {
        return mutableListOf(MapboxNavigationView(reactContext))
    }

    override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): MutableList<NativeModule> {
        return mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

Android MainApplication.java:

```
package com.mapboxpoc;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

          @Override protected List<ReactPackage>getPackages() {
              List<ReactPackage>packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();

              packages.add(new MapboxNavigationPackage());
              packages.add(new TestPackage());
              return packages;
          }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
}
```

React-Native Component Import (MapboxNavigationView.tsx):

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

export const MapboxNavigation = requireNativeComponent('MapboxNavigationView');
```

App.tsx:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React from 'react';
import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import {
    Button,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    StatusBar,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    useColorScheme,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

import {
    Colors,
    DebugInstructions,
    Header,
    ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import { MapboxNavigation }  from './src/MapboxNavigationView';

type SectionProps = PropsWithChildren<{
    title: string;
}>;

function Section({ children, title }: SectionProps): JSX.Element {
    const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
    return (
        <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
            <Text
                style={[
                    styles.sectionTitle,
                    {
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                    },
                ]}>
                {title}
            </Text>
            <Text
                style={[
                    styles.sectionDescription,
                    {
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.light : Colors.dark,
                    },
                ]}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

function App(): JSX.Element {
    const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

    const backgroundStyle = {
        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
    };

    const { MapboxNavigationModule, TestModule } = NativeModules;

    const NewModuleButton = () => {
        const onPress = () => {
            MapboxNavigationModule.createNavigationEvent('25 Commerce Crescent, Kramerville, Johannesburg, 2090');
        };
        return (
            <Button
                title="Click to invoke your navigation module!"
                color="#841584"
                onPress={onPress}
            />
        );
    };

    const TestModuleButton = () => {
        const onPress = () => {
            TestModule.createTestEvent('25 Commerce Crescent, Kramerville, Johannesburg, 2090');
        };
        return (
            <Button
                title="Click to invoke your test module!"
                color="#841584"
                onPress={onPress}
            />
        );
    };

    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                {
                    title: 'Need to know where you are Permission',
                    message:
                        'Gief location access ' +
                        'so that I can navigate you.',
                    buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    buttonPositive: 'OK',
                },
            );
            console.log(granted)
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('You can use location');
            } else {
                console.log('Location permission denied');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    };

    const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
        try {
            const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
                {
                    title: 'Be notifed Dammit Permission',
                    message:
                        'Gief permissions to notify ' +
                        'so that I can notify you.',
                    buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    buttonPositive: 'OK',
                },
            );
              console.log(granted)
            if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                console.log('You can use notfications');
            } else {
                console.log('Notifications permission denied');
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(err);
        }
    };

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
            <StatusBar
                barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
                backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
            />
            <ScrollView
                contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
                style={backgroundStyle}>
                <Header />
                <View
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                    }}>
                    <NewModuleButton />
                    <TestModuleButton />
                    <Button title="request location permissions" onPress={requestLocationPermission} />
                    <Button title="request notification permissions" onPress={requestNotificationPermission} />
                    <MapboxNavigation/>
                    <Section title="Step One">
                        Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.tsx</Text> to change this
                        screen and then come back to see your edits.
                    </Section>
                    <Section title="See Your Changes">
                        <ReloadInstructions />
                    </Section>
                    <Section title="Debug">
                        <DebugInstructions />
                    </Section>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sectionContainer: {
        marginTop: 32,
        paddingHorizontal: 24,
    },
    sectionTitle: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '600',
    },
    sectionDescription: {
        marginTop: 8,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: '400',
    },
    highlight: {
        fontWeight: '700',
    },
});

export default App;
```

I have an Adb logcat available - just running out of space in the thread!

Any advice would be greatly appreciated - as with most things, it's probably user error.

I've pulled down and implemented the examples from the Mapbox docs relatively easily in a native android app. When it comes to getting it running in react-native though, I cannot seem come right and there are relatively few resources available for it.

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to react native 0.70XX seems to fix it